# getElementById() is always showing NULL status

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I am going through lessons of JavaScript about Event Handlers, while doing so I am starting very basic which is `getElementById()`. Below is my HTML and JavaScript Code. The following code has images tag also but I am new user to SO that's why they didn't allowed me to post them in the exact way. So consider `src` tags to be fully complaint.

```
<div class="considerVisiting">
  <img src="images/bq-twitter" id="mainImage" alt="BeQRious Twitter"> 
</div>
```

and here is the JavaScript Code:

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
var imageArray = [images/1-btn, images/download-as-you-like];
var imageIndex = 0;

function changeImage() {

  myImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex++;

  if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
    imageIndex=0;
  }
}

setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
```

This code will change the mainImage Picture every 5 seconds. But the problem I am facing is that when I run this script using FireBug in Mozilla it says:

```
 > Error : myImage is Null
```

and nothing happens with regard to the script.

Comment: Does the element exist in the DOM *before* the JavaScript executes? (Bearing in mind that the JavaScript will run as soon as the browser encounters it), have you wrapped it in a `document.ready` event handler? Or tried putting the JS in a `script` block at the foot of the page? So it's executed after the DOM is put together?

Comment: are you sure the attribute on your `img` element (in your soruce) is an `id`?  Internet Explorer has a bug where it will match on the name instead of the ID, but other browsers will correctly complain.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<img src="images/bq-twitter" **id="mainImage"** alt="BeQRious Twitter" />
```

To:

```
<img src="images/bq-twitter" id="mainImage" alt="BeQRious Twitter" />
```

The ** are not valid.

Comment: Possibly, but I was hoping that was just a means of emphasising the `id` attribute...

Answer (score 0):

`.getElementById()` is supposed to return null if no element of the specified id exists, so the behaviour you are seeing is correct if your script is running before the element in question is parsed. Just a guess, but is your script in the `<head>` of your document? Script (including in the head) runs as the browser encounters it while it is parsing the document from top to bottom. Your script can only access elements that have already been parsed by the browser, i.e., elements higher/earlier in the document, so if you move your `<script>` section to the bottom of the body it will (obviously) be after all your elements and will be able to access them.

The other way to do it is to run your code "onload" or on "document.ready" of the document. "onload" is an event that the browser will execute only after the whole document has been loaded.

The only other thing that jumps out as obviously wrong is this line:

```
var imageArray= [images/1-btn,images/download-as-you-like];
```

I assume this was meant to be an array of strings, and so should be like this:

```
var imageArray= ["images/1-btn", "images/download-as-you-like"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the values in the array should be string literals, i.e.

```
> var imageArray = [images/1-btn, images/download-as-you-like];
```

should be:

```
var imageArray = ['images/1-btn', 'images/download-as-you-like'];
```

Also, don't use 'setAttribute' unless you have a good reason. Use DOM properties instead as 'setAttribute' is buggy and unreliable in some cases. It is also more natural to read as you are really trying to set a property of a DOM object, not an attribute of HTML markup, so:

```
> myImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
```

should be:

```
myImage.src = imageArray[imageIndex];
```

Also:

```
> if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
>   imageIndex=0;
> }
```

can be managed using the modulus operator %:

```
  imageIndex = imageIndex % imageArray.length;
```

The whole function can be reduced to:

```
function changeImage() {
  myImage.src = imageArray[index++ % imageArray.length];
}
```

You can also get rid of the global variables by using closures:

```
var changeImage = (function() {

    var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
    var imageArray = ['images/1-btn', 'images/download-as-you-like'];
    var imageIndex = 0;

    return function () {
        myImage.src = imageArray[index++ % imageArray.length];
    }
}());
```

However, you must run the above code **after** the element with id *mainImage* exists in the DOM (e.g. you can't run it from the head). It is likely better to call the function and pass the id using *window.onload*.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful suggestions  ... it helped me alot :) :) thanks

Comment: i was doing everything perfect, n ** was used in img tag just on stack so that it becomes prominent other ways everything was strictly following HTML4 Doc type... the thing what i was using i placed the script in the head so the browser already executed the script before it reached down to the DOM tree... 

i have corrected it and it worked =D thank you once again